# Periodic Table of Elements (Python-tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

This is a code that generates the periodic table where each element is represented as a button and info about the element is produced when that specific button is pressed. I wanted to make this code shorter by changing the way the buttons (elements) for each column of the periodic table are generated. Plus, how to add functionality so that I can toggle between the buttons by pressing the arrow keys?
**Is there a simpler, shorter, way of generating the buttons in this code?**

```
import tkinter as tk
# Creates and Initiates class 'App'


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent

        self.winfo_toplevel().title("Periodic Table of the Elements")
        self.topLabel = tk.Label(self, text="Click the element you would like information about.", font=20)
        self.topLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=18)


        # Names of tk.Buttons in column 1
        column1 = [
            ('H', 'Hydrogen', 'Atomic # = 1\nAtomic Weight =1.01\nState = Gas\nCategory = Alkali Metals'),
            ('Li', 'Lithium', 'Atomic # = 3\nAtomic Weight = 6.94\nState = Solid\nCategory = Alkali Metals'),
            ('Na', 'Sodium', 'Atomic # = 11\nAtomic Weight = 22.99\nState = Solid\nCategory = Alkali Metals'),
            ('K', 'Potassium', 'Atomic # = 19\nAtomic Weight = 39.10\nState = Solid\nCategory = Alkali Metals'),
            ('Rb', 'Rubidium', 'Atomic # = 37\nAtomic Weight = 85.47\nState = Solid\nCategory = Alkali Metals'),
            ('Cs', 'Cesium', 'Atomic # = 55\nAtomic Weight = 132.91\nState = Solid\nCategory = Alkali Metals'),
            ('Fr', 'Francium', 'Atomic # = 87\nAtomic Weight = 223.00\nState = Solid\nCategory = Alkali Metals')]
        # create all tk.Buttons with a loop
        r = 1
        c = 0
        for b in column1: 
            tk.Button(self,
                      text=b[0],
                      width=5,
                      height=2,
                      bg="grey",
                      command=lambda text=b:  self.name(text[1]) & self.info(text[2])).grid(row=r, column=c)
            r += 1
            if r > 7: 
                r = 1
                c += 1

        column2 = [
            ('Be', 'Beryllium', 'Atomic # = 4\nAtomic Weight = 9.01\nState = Solid\nCategory = Alkaline Earth Metals'),
            ('Mg', 'Magnesium', 'Atomic # = 12\nAtomic Weight = 24.31\nState = Solid\nCategory = Alkaline Earth Metal'),
            ('Ca', 'Calcium', 'Atomic # = 20\nAtomic Weight = 40.08\nState = Solid\nCategory = Alkaline Earth Metals'),
            ('Sr', 'Strontium', 'Atomic # = 38\nAtomic Weight = 87.62\nState = Solid\nCategory = Alkaline Earth Metal'),
            ('Ba', 'Barium', 'Atomic # = 56\nAtomic Weight = 137.33\nState = Solid\nCategory = Alkaline Earth Metals'),
            ('Ra', 'Radium', 'Atomic # = 88\nAtomic Weight = 226.03\nState = Solid\nCategory = Alkaline Earth Metals')]
        r = 2
        c = 1
        for b in column2: 
            tk.Button(self,
                      text=b[0],
                      width=5,
                      height=2,
                      bg="light green",
                      command=lambda text=b:  self.name(text[1]) & self.info(text[2])).grid(row=r, column=c)
            r += 1
            if r > 7: 
                r = 1
                c += 1

        column3 = [
            ('Sc', 'Scandium', 'Atomic # = 21\nAtomic Weight = 44.96\nState = Solid\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Y', 'Yttrium', 'Atomic # = 39\nAtomic Weight = 88.91\nState = Solid\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('La   >|', 'Lanthanum', 'Atomic # = 57\nAtomic Weight = 138.91\nState = Solid\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Ac   >|', 'Actinium', 'Atomic # = 89\nAtomic Weight = 227.03\nState = Solid\nCategory = Trans Metals')]
        r = 4
        c = 2
        for b in column3: 
            tk.Button(self,
                      text=b[0],
                      width=5,
                      height=2,
                      bg="light goldenrod",
                      command=lambda text=b: self.name(text[1]) & self.info(text[2])).grid(row=r, column=c)
            r += 1
            if r > 7: 
                r = 1
                c += 1

        column4 = [
            ('Ti', 'Titanium', 'Atomic # = 22\nAtomic Weight = 47.90\nState = Solid\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Zr', 'Zirconium', 'Atomic # = 40\nAtomic Weight = 91.22\nState = Solid\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Hf', 'Hanium', 'Atomic # = 72\nAtomic Weight = 178.49\nState = Solid\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Rf', 'Rutherfordium', 'Atomic # = 104\nAtomic Weight = 261.00\nState = Synthetic\nCategory = Tran Metal')]
        r = 4
        c = 3
        for b in column4: 
            tk.Button(self,
                      text=b[0],
                      width=5,
                      height=2,
                      bg="light goldenrod",
                      command=lambda text=b: self.name(text[1]) & self.info(text[2])).grid(row=r, column=c)
            r += 1
            if r > 10: 
                r = 1
                c += 1

        column5 = [
            ('V', 'Vanadium', 'Atomic # = 23\nAtomic Weight = 50.94\nState = Solid\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Nb', 'Niobium', 'Atomic # = 41\nAtomic Weight = 92.91\nState = Solid\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Ta', 'Tantalum', 'Atomic # = 73\nAtomic Weight = 180.95\nState = Solid\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Ha', 'Hahnium', 'Atomic # = 105\nAtomic Weight = 262.00\nState = Synthetic\nCategory = Trans Metals')]
        r = 4
        c = 4
        for b in column5: 
            tk.Button(self,
                      text=b[0],
                      width=5, height=2,
                      bg="light goldenrod",
                      command=lambda text=b: self.name(text[1]) & self.info(text[2])).grid(row=r, column=c)
            r += 1
            if r > 10: 
                r = 1
                c += 1

        column6 = [
            ('Cr', 'Chromium', 'Atomic # = 24\nAtomic Weight = 51.99\nState = Solid\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Mo', 'Molybdenum', 'Atomic # = 42\nAtomic Weight = 95.94\nState = Solid\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('W', 'Tungsten', 'Atomic # = 74\nAtomic Weight = 183.85\nState = Solid\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Sg', 'Seaborgium', 'Atomic # = 106\nAtomic Weight = 266.00\nState = Synthetic\nCategory = Trans Metals')]
        r = 4
        c = 5
        for b in column6: 
            tk.Button(self,
                      text=b[0],
                      width=5,
                      height=2,
                      bg="light goldenrod",
                      command=lambda text=b:  self.name(text[1]) & self.info(text[2])).grid(row=r, column=c)
            r += 1
            if r > 7: 
                r = 1
                c += 1

        column7 = [
            ('Mn', 'Manganese', 'Atomic # = 25\nAtomic Weight = 178.49\nState = Solid\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Tc', 'Technetium', 'Atomic # = 43\nAtomic Weight = 178.49\nState = Synthetic\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Re', 'Rhenium', 'Atomic # = 75\nAtomic Weight = 178.49\nState = Solid\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Bh', 'Bohrium', 'Atomic # = 107\nAtomic Weight = 262.00\nState = Synthetic\nCategory = Trans Metals')]
        r = 4
        c = 6
        for b in column7: 
            tk.Button(self,
                      text=b[0],
                      width=5,
                      height=2,
                      bg="light goldenrod",
                      command=lambda text=b:  self.name(text[1]) & self.info(text[2])).grid(row=r, column=c)
            r += 1
            if r > 7: 
                r = 1
                c += 1

        column8 = [
            ('Fe', 'Iron', 'Atomic # = 26\nAtomic Weight = 55.85\nState = Solid\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Ru', 'Ruthenium', 'Atomic # = 44\nAtomic Weight = 101.07\nState = Solid\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Os', 'Osmium', 'Atomic # = 76\nAtomic Weight = 190.20\nState = Solid\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Hs', 'Hassium', 'Atomic # = 108\nAtomic Weight = 265.00\nState = Synthetic\nCategory = Trans Metals')]
        r = 4
        c = 7
        for b in column8: 
            tk.Button(self,
                      text=b[0],
                      width=5,
                      height=2,
                      bg="light goldenrod",
                      command=lambda text=b: self.name(text[1]) & self.info(text[2])).grid(row=r, column=c)
            r += 1
            if r > 7: 
                r = 1
                c += 1

        column9 = [
            ('Co', 'Cobalt', 'Atomic # = 27\nAtomic Weight = 58.93\nState = Solid\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Rh', 'Rhodium', 'Atomic # = 45\nAtomic Weight = 102.91\nState = Solid\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Ir', 'Iridium', 'Atomic # = 77\nAtomic Weight = 192.22\nState = Solid\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Mt', 'Meitnerium', 'Atomic # = 109\nAtomic Weight = 266.00\nState = Synthetic\nCategory = Trans Metals')]
        r = 4
        c = 8
        for b in column9: 
            tk.Button(self,
                      text=b[0],
                      width=5,
                      height=2,
                      bg="light goldenrod",
                      command=lambda text=b: self.name(text[1]) & self.info(text[2])).grid(row=r, column=c)
            r += 1
            if r > 7: 
                r = 1
                c += 1

        column10 = [
            ('Ni', 'Nickle', 'Atomic # = 28\nAtomic Weight = 58.70\nState = Solid\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Pd', 'Palladium', 'Atomic # = 46\nAtomic Weight = 106.40\nState = Solid\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Pt', 'Platinum', 'Atomic # = 78\nAtomic Weight = 195.09\nState = Solid\nCategory = Trans Metals')]
        r = 4
        c = 9
        for b in column10: 
            tk.Button(self,
                      text=b[0],
                      width=5,
                      height=2,
                      bg="light goldenrod",
                      command=lambda text=b: self.name(text[1]) & self.info(text[2])).grid(row=r, column=c)
            r += 1
            if r > 7: 
                r = 1
                c += 1

        column11 = [
            ('Cu', 'Copper', 'Atomic # = 29\nAtomic Weight = 63.55\nState = Solid\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Ag', 'Silver', 'Atomic # = 47\nAtomic Weight = 107.97\nState = Solid\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Au', 'Gold', 'Atomic # = 79\nAtomic Weight = 196.97\nState = Solid\nCategory = Trans Metals')]
        r = 4
        c = 10
        for b in column11: 
            tk.Button(self,
                      text=b[0],
                      width=5,
                      height=2,
                      bg="light goldenrod",
                      command=lambda text=b:  self.name(text[1]) & self.info(text[2])).grid(row=r, column=c)
            r += 1
            if r > 7: 
                r = 1
                c += 1

        column12 = [
            ('Zn', 'Zinc', 'Atomic # = 30\nAtomic Weight = 65.37\nState = Solid\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Cd', 'Cadmium', 'Atomic # = 48\nAtomic Weight = 112.41\nState = Solid\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Hg', 'Mercury', 'Atomic # = 80\nAtomic Weight = 200.59\nState = Liquid\nCategory = Trans Metals')]
        r = 4
        c = 11
        for b in column12: 
            tk.Button(self,
                      text=b[0],
                      width=5,
                      height=2,
                      bg="light goldenrod",
                      command=lambda text=b:  self.name(text[1]) & self.info(text[2])).grid(row=r, column=c)
            r += 1
            if r > 7: 
                r = 1
                c += 1

        column13_1 = [
            ('B', 'Boron', 'Atomic # = 5\nAtomic Weight = 10.81\nState = Solid\nCategory = Nonmetals')]
        r = 2
        c = 12
        for b in column13_1: 
            tk.Button(self,
                      text=b[0],
                      width=5,
                      height=2,
                      bg="Light Blue",
                      command=lambda text=b: self.name(text[1]) & self.info(text[2])).grid(row=r, column=c)
            r += 1
            if r > 7: 
                r = 1
                c += 1

        column13_2 = [
            ('Al', 'Aluminum', 'Atomic # = 13\nAtomic Weight = 26.98\nState = Solid\nCategory = Other Metals'),
            ('Ga', 'Gallium', 'Atomic # = 31\nAtomic Weight = 69.72\nState = Solid\nCategory = Other Metals'),
            ('In', 'Indium', 'Atomic # = 49\nAtomic Weight = 69.72\nState = Solid\nCategory = Other Metals'),
            ('Ti', 'Thallium', 'Atomic # = 81\nAtomic Weight = 204.37\nState = Solid\nCategory = Other Metals')]
        r = 3
        c = 12
        for b in column13_2: 
            tk.Button(self,
                      text=b[0],
                      width=5,
                      height=2,
                      bg="Light Pink",
                      command=lambda text=b: self.name(text[1]) & self.info(text[2])).grid(row=r, column=c)
            r += 1
            if r > 7: 
                r = 1
                c += 1

        column14_1 = [
            ('C', 'Carbon', 'Atomic # = 6\nAtomic Weight = 12.01\nState = Solid\nCategory = Nonmetals'),
            ('Si', 'Silicon', 'Atomic # = 14\nAtomic Weight = 28.09\nState = Solid\nCategory = Nonmetals')]
        r = 2
        c = 13
        for b in column14_1: 
            tk.Button(self,
                      text=b[0],
                      width=5,
                      height=2,
                      bg="Light Blue",
                      command=lambda text=b: self.name(text[1]) & self.info(text[2])).grid(row=r, column=c)
            r += 1
            if r > 7: 
                r = 1
                c += 1

        column14_2 = [
            ('Ge', 'Germanium', 'Atomic # = 32\nAtomic Weight = 72.59\nState = Solid\nCategory = Other Metals'),
            ('Sn', 'Tin', 'Atomic # = 50\nAtomic Weight = 118.69\nState = Solid\nCategory = Other Metals'),
            ('Pb', 'Lead', 'Atomic # = 82\nAtomic Weight = 207.20\nState = Solid\nCategory = Other Metals')]
        r = 4
        c = 13
        for b in column14_2: 
            tk.Button(self,
                      text=b[0],
                      width=5,
                      height=2,
                      bg="Light Pink",
                      command=lambda text=b: self.name(text[1]) & self.info(text[2])).grid(row=r, column=c)
            r += 1
            if r > 7: 
                r = 1
                c += 1

        column15_1 = [
            ('N', 'Nitrogen', 'Atomic # = 7\nAtomic Weight = 14.01\nState = Gas\nCategory = Nonmetals'),
            ('P', 'Phosphorus', 'Atomic # = 15\nAtomic Weight = 30.97\nState = Solid\nCategory = Nonmetals'),
            ('As', 'Arsenic', 'Atomic # = 33\nAtomic Weight = 74.92\nState = Solid\nCategory = Nonmetals')]
        r = 2
        c = 14
        for b in column15_1: 
            tk.Button(self,
                      text=b[0],
                      width=5,
                      height=2,
                      bg="Light Blue",
                      command=lambda text=b: self.name(text[1]) & self.info(text[2])).grid(row=r, column=c)
            r += 1
            if r > 7: 
                r = 1
                c += 1

        column15_2 = [
            ('Sb', 'Antimony', 'Atomic # = 51\nAtomic Weight = 121.75\nState = Solid\nCategory = Other Metals'),
            ('Bi', 'Bismuth', 'Atomic # = 83\nAtomic Weight = 208.98\nState = Solid\nCategory = Other Metals')]
        r = 5
        c = 14
        for b in column15_2: 
            tk.Button(self,
                      text=b[0],
                      width=5,
                      height=2,
                      bg="Light Pink",
                      command=lambda text=b: self.name(text[1]) & self.info(text[2])).grid(row=r, column=c)
            r += 1
            if r > 7: 
                r = 1
                c += 1

        column16_1 = [
            ('O', 'Oxygen', 'Atomic # = 8\nAtomic Weight = 15.99\nState = Gas\nCategory = Nonmetals'),
            ('S', 'Sulfur', 'Atomic # = 16\nAtomic Weight = 32.06\nState = Solid\nCategory = Nonmetals'),
            ('Se', 'Selenium', 'Atomic # = 34\nAtomic Weight = 78.96\nState = Solid\nCategory = Nonmetals'),
            ('Te', 'Tellurium', 'Atomic # = 52\nAtomic Weight = 127.60\nState = Solid\nCategory = Nonmetals')]
        r = 2
        c = 15
        for b in column16_1: 
            tk.Button(self,
                      text=b[0],
                      width=5,
                      height=2,
                      bg="Light Blue",
                      command=lambda text=b: self.name(text[1]) & self.info(text[2])).grid(row=r, column=c)
            r += 1
            if r > 7: 
                r = 1
                c += 1

        column16_2 = [
            ('Po', 'Polonium', 'Atomic # = 84\nAtomic Weight = 209.00\nState = Solid\nCategory = Other Metals')]
        r = 6
        c = 15
        for b in column16_2: 
            tk.Button(self,
                      text=b[0],
                      width=5,
                      height=2,
                      bg="Light Pink",
                      command=lambda text=b: self.name(text[1]) & self.info(text[2])).grid(row=r, column=c)
            r += 1
            if r > 7: 
                r = 1
                c += 1

        column17 = [
            ('F', 'Fluorine', 'Atomic # = 9\nAtomic Weight = 18.99\nState = Gas\nCategory = Nonmetals'),
            ('Cl', 'Chlorine', 'Atomic # = 17\nAtomic Weight = 35.45\nState = Gas\nCategory = Nonmetals'),
            ('Br', 'Bromine', 'Atomic # = 35\nAtomic Weight = 79.90\nState = Liquid\nCategory = Nonmetals'),
            ('I', 'Iodine', 'Atomic # = 53\nAtomic Weight = 126.90\nState = Solid\nCategory = Nonmetals'),
            ('At', 'Astatine', 'Atomic # = 85\nAtomic Weight = 210.00\nState = Solid\nCategory = Nonmetals')]
        r = 2
        c = 16
        for b in column17: 
            tk.Button(self,
                      text=b[0],
                      width=5,
                      height=2,
                      bg="Light Blue",
                      command=lambda text=b: self.name(text[1]) & self.info(text[2])).grid(row=r, column=c)
            r += 1
            if r > 7: 
                r = 1
                c += 1

        column18 = [
            ('He', 'Helium', 'Atomic # = 2\nAtomic Weight = 4.00\nState = Gas\nCategory = Nobel Gases'),
            ('Ne', 'Neon', 'Atomic # = 10\nAtomic Weight = 20.18\nState = Gas\nCategory = Nobel Gases'),
            ('Ar', 'Argon', 'Atomic # = 18\nAtomic Weight = 39.95\nState = Gas\nCategory = Nobel Gases'),
            ('Kr', 'Krypton', 'Atomic # = 36\nAtomic Weight = 83.80\nState = Gas\nCategory = Nobel Gases'),
            ('Xe', 'Xenon', 'Atomic # = 54\nAtomic Weight = 131.30\nState = Gas\nCategory = Nobel Gases'),
            ('Rn', 'Radon', 'Atomic # = 86\nAtomic Weight = 222.00\nState = Gas\nCategory = Nobel Gases')]
        r = 1
        c = 17
        for b in column18: 
            tk.Button(self,
                      text=b[0],
                      width=5,
                      height=2,
                      bg="indian red",
                      command=lambda text=b: self.name(text[1]) & self.info(text[2])).grid(row=r, column=c)
            r += 1
            if r > 7: 
                r = 1
                c += 1

        self.fillerLine = tk.Label(self, text="")
        self.fillerLine.grid(row=10, column=0)

        lanthanide = [
            ('>| Ce', 'Cerium', 'Atomic # = 58\nAtomic Weight = 140.12\nState = Solid\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Pr', 'Praseodymium', 'Atomic # = 59\nAtomic Weight = 140.91\nState = Solid\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Nd', 'Neodymium', 'Atomic # = 60\nAtomic Weight = 144.24\nState = Solid\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Pm', 'Promethium', 'Atomic # = 61\nAtomic Weight = 145.00\nState = Synthetic\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Sm', 'Samarium', 'Atomic # = 62\nAtomic Weight = 150.40\nState = Solid\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Eu', 'Europium', 'Atomic # = 63\nAtomic Weight = 151.96\nState = Solid\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Gd', 'Gadolinium', 'Atomic # = 64\nAtomic Weight = 157.25\nState = Solid\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Tb', 'Terbium', 'Atomic # = 65\nAtomic Weight = 158.93\nState = Solid\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Dy', 'Dyprosium', 'Atomic # = 66\nAtomic Weight = 162.50\nState = Solid\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Ho', 'Holmium', 'Atomic # = 67\nAtomic Weight = 164.93\nState = Solid\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Er', 'Erbium', 'Atomic # = 68\nAtomic Weight = 167.26\nState = Solid\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Tm', 'Thulium', 'Atomic # = 69\nAtomic Weight = 168.93\nState = Solid\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Yb', 'Ytterbium', 'Atomic # = 70\nAtomic Weight = 173.04\nState = Solid\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Lu', 'Lutetium', 'Atomic # = 71\nAtomic Weight = 174.97\nState = Solid\nCategory = Trans Metals')]
        r = 11
        c = 3
        for b in lanthanide: 
            tk.Button(self,
                      text=b[0],
                      width=5,
                      height=2,
                      bg="light goldenrod",
                      command=lambda text=b: self.name(text[1]) & self.info(text[2])).grid(row=r, column=c)
            c += 1
            if c > 18: 
                c = 1
                r += 1

        actinide = [
            ('>| Th', 'Thorium', 'Atomic # = 90\nAtomic Weight = 232.04\nState = Solid\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Pa', 'Protactinium', 'Atomic # = 91\nAtomic Weight = 231.04\nState = Solid\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('U', 'Uranium', 'Atomic # = 92\nAtomic Weight = 238.03\nState = Solid\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Np', 'Neptunium', 'Atomic # = 93\nAtomic Weight = 237.05\nState = Synthetic\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Pu', 'Plutonium', 'Atomic # = 94\nAtomic Weight = 244.00\nState = Synthetic\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Am', 'Americium', 'Atomic # = 95\nAtomic Weight = 243.00\nState = Synthetic\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Cm', 'Curium', 'Atomic # = 96\nAtomic Weight = 247\nState = Synthetic\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Bk', 'Berkelium', 'Atomic # = 97\nAtomic Weight = 247\nState = Synthetic\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Cf', 'Californium', 'Atomic # = 98\nAtomic Weight = 247\nState = Synthetic\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Es', 'Einsteinium', 'Atomic # = 99\nAtomic Weight = 252.00\nState = Synthetic\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Fm', 'Fermium', 'Atomic # = 100\nAtomic Weight = 257.00\nState = Synthetic\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Md', 'Mendelevium', 'Atomic # = 101\nAtomic Weight = 260.00\nState = Synthetic\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('No', 'Nobelium', 'Atomic # = 102\nAtomic Weight = 259\nState = Synthetic\nCategory = Trans Metals'),
            ('Lr', 'Lawrencium', 'Atomic # = 103\nAtomic Weight = 262\nState = Synthetic\nCategory = Trans Metals')]
        r = 12
        c = 3
        for b in actinide:
            tk.Button(self,
                      text=b[0],
                      width=5,
                      height=2,
                      bg="light goldenrod",
                      command=lambda text=b: self.name(text[1]) & self.info(text[2])).grid(row=r, column=c)
            c += 1
            if c > 18: 
                c = 1
                r += 1

        reset = [
            ('Reset', 'Click the element you would like information about.', '')]
        r = 12
        c = 0
        for b in reset: 
            tk.Button(self,
                      text=b[0],
                      width=5,
                      height=2,
                      bg= "black",
                      fg = "white",
                      command=lambda text=b: self.name(text[1]) & self.info(text[2])).grid(row=r, column=c)
            r += 1
            if r > 7: 
                r = 1
                c += 1

        self.infoLine = tk.Label(self, text="", justify='left')
        self.infoLine.grid(row=1, column=3, columnspan=10, rowspan=4)

    


    # Replaces Label at the top with the name of whichever element tk.Button was pressed
    def name(self, text): 
        self.topLabel.config(text=text)

    # Displays information on the element of whichever element tk.Button was pressed
    def info(self, text): 
        self.infoLine.config(text=text)



root = tk.Tk()
a = App(root)
a.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew') 
a.mainloop()
```

Comment: A great project! Please correct alias for Thallium (81) in column13_2: 'Ti' -> 'Tl'

Comment: This is now one of three similar posts making a period table in tkinter. I encourage you to read the other two to get ideas.

Comment: A screenshot showing the app would be nice and useful.

Comment: Please don't edit your code after you have received answers.  You could post improved code as a new question, as an answer, or as a link to an external site - as described in [I improved my code based on the reviews. What next?](/help/someone-answers#help-post-body).  I have rolled back the edit, so the answers make sense again.

Answer (score 4):

Cool project,
how about this approach:

1. Move elements data to a JSON - This answers:

   > I wanted to make this code shorter ...

   By moving elements information to a separate file you make main file much smaller by separating concerns between Data and Business logic. Also this allows you to easily reuse elements data for other projects.
   (Please see `elements.json` below)
2. Make a layout and color maps for buttons - This answers:

   > Is there a simpler, ... way of generating the buttons in this code?

   You create a layout map for each element button in a separate file, and use only one method **`build_elements_table`**() to generate the whole table of elements.
   (Please see `elements_layout_map.json` below)
3. This code executes but also throws exception at the end:

   ```py
    command=lambda text=b: self.name(text[1]) & self.info(text[2])
   ```

   if you want to execute several methods in this lambda expression: use comma separator instead of "&" and put method calls in braces like this:

   ```py
    command=lambda text=b: (self.name(text[1]), self.info(text[2]))
   ```
4. Regarding selecting buttons by arrows (not implemented in code below):

   1. add event handlers for each arrow press
   2. create `button_layout_map` with references on each button
   3. track current selected button row/column indexes in `button_layout_map`.

P.S.
(please create four files from the code below and put them in one folder)

## `periodic_table.py`

```
import tkinter as tk

class PeriodicTable(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        '''Initializes a new instance of the PeriodicTable class'''

        # strings
        # TODO: move strings to separate localizable dictionary
        self.default_title = "Periodic Table of the Elements"
        self.default_header = "Click the element you would like information about."
        self.reset_button_text = "Reset"

        # get data for building the elements table
        self.elements_data = self.get_elements_data()
        self.elements_map = self.get_elements_map()
        self.elements_color_map = self.get_elements_color_map()

        # add controls on UI
        self.buttons = {}
        self.parent = parent
        self.winfo_toplevel().title(self.default_title)
        self.topLabel = tk.Label(self, text=self.default_header, font=20)
        self.topLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=18)
        self.build_elements_table()
        self.infoLine = tk.Label(self, text="", justify='left')
        self.infoLine.grid(row=1, column=3, columnspan=10, rowspan=4)
        self.reset_button = tk.Button(self, text=self.reset_button_text, width=5, height=2, bg= "black", fg = "white",
                                      command=lambda text="": (self.change_header(self.default_header), self.change_info("")))
        self.reset_button.grid(row=12, column=0)

    def get_elements_data(self):
        '''Loads elements data from json'''

        import json
        with open('elements.json', 'r') as file:
            return json.loads(file.read())

    def get_elements_map(self):
        '''Loads elements layout map from json'''

        import json
        with open('elements_layout_map.json', 'r') as file:
            return json.loads(file.read())

    def get_elements_color_map(self):
        '''Load elements map from json'''

        import json
        with open('color_map.json', 'r') as file:
            return json.loads(file.read())

    def build_elements_table(self):
        '''Adds button controls for each element on UI'''

        for element in self.elements_data["elements"]:

            name = element["Alias"]
            row = self.elements_map["map"][element["Alias"]]["row"]
            col = self.elements_map["map"][element["Alias"]]["column"]
            color = self.elements_color_map['map'][element["Categories"][0]]

            def get_info(element):
                return "Atomic # = {}\nAtomic Weight = {}\nState = {}\nCategory = {}".format(
                       element['Atomic Number'],
                       element['Atomic Weight'],
                       element['State'],
                       element['Categories'][0])

            button = tk.Button(self, text=element["Alias"], width=5, height=2, bg=color,
                               command=lambda  e=element: (self.change_header(e["Name"]), self.change_info(get_info(e))))
            
            button.grid(row=row, column=col)            
            self.buttons[element["Alias"]] = button

        self.fillerLine = tk.Label(self, text="")
        self.fillerLine.grid(row=10, column=0)

    def change_header(self, text): 
        '''Changes Label text at the top with the name of whichever 
        element tk.Button was pressed'''

        self.topLabel.config(text=text)

    def change_info(self, text):
        '''Displays information on the element of 
        whichever element tk.Button was pressed'''

        self.infoLine.config(text=text)

root = tk.Tk()
app = PeriodicTable(root)
app.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew') 
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
app.mainloop()
```

## `elements.json`

```
{
    "version": 1,
    "elements": [
        {
            "Alias": "H",
            "Name": "Hydrogen",
            "Atomic Number": 1,
            "Atomic Weight": 1.01,
            "State": "Gas",
            "Categories": ["Alkali Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Li",
            "Name": "Lithium",
            "Atomic Number": 3,
            "Atomic Weight": 6.94,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Alkali Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Na",
            "Name": "Sodium",
            "Atomic Number": 11,
            "Atomic Weight": 22.99,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Alkali Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "K",
            "Name": "Potassium",
            "Atomic Number": 19,
            "Atomic Weight": 39.10,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Alkali Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Rb",
            "Name": "Rubidium",
            "Atomic Number": 37,
            "Atomic Weight": 85.47,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Alkali Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Cs",
            "Name": "Cesium",
            "Atomic Number": 55,
            "Atomic Weight": 132.91,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Alkali Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Fr",
            "Name": "Francium",
            "Atomic Number": 87,
            "Atomic Weight": 223.00,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Alkali Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Be",
            "Name": "Beryllium",
            "Atomic Number": 4,
            "Atomic Weight": 9.01,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Alkaline Earth Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Mg",
            "Name": "Magnesium",
            "Atomic Number": 12,
            "Atomic Weight": 24.31,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Alkaline Earth Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Ca",
            "Name": "Calcium",
            "Atomic Number": 20,
            "Atomic Weight": 40.08,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Alkaline Earth Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Sr",
            "Name": "Strontium",
            "Atomic Number": 38,
            "Atomic Weight": 87.62,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Alkaline Earth Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Ba",
            "Name": "Barium",
            "Atomic Number": 56,
            "Atomic Weight": 137.33,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Alkaline Earth Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Ra",
            "Name": "Radium",
            "Atomic Number": 88,
            "Atomic Weight": 226.03,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Alkaline Earth Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Sc",
            "Name": "Scandium",
            "Atomic Number": 21,
            "Atomic Weight": 44.96,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Y",
            "Name": "Yttrium",
            "Atomic Number": 39,
            "Atomic Weight": 88.91,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "La   >|",
            "Name": "Lanthanum",
            "Atomic Number": 57,
            "Atomic Weight": 138.91,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Ac   >|",
            "Name": "Actinium",
            "Atomic Number": 89,
            "Atomic Weight": 227.03,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Ti",
            "Name": "Titanium",
            "Atomic Number": 22,
            "Atomic Weight": 47.90,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Zr",
            "Name": "Zirconium",
            "Atomic Number": 40,
            "Atomic Weight": 91.22,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Hf",
            "Name": "Hanium",
            "Atomic Number": 72,
            "Atomic Weight": 178.49,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Rf",
            "Name": "Rutherfordium",
            "Atomic Number": 104,
            "Atomic Weight": 261.00,
            "State": "Synthetic",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "V",
            "Name": "Vanadium",
            "Atomic Number": 23,
            "Atomic Weight": 50.94,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Nb",
            "Name": "Niobium",
            "Atomic Number": 41,
            "Atomic Weight": 92.91,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Ta",
            "Name": "Tantalum",
            "Atomic Number": 73,
            "Atomic Weight": 180.95,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Ha",
            "Name": "Hahnium",
            "Atomic Number": 105,
            "Atomic Weight": 262.00,
            "State": "Synthetic",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Cr",
            "Name": "Chromium",
            "Atomic Number": 24,
            "Atomic Weight": 51.99,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Mo",
            "Name": "Molybdenum",
            "Atomic Number": 42,
            "Atomic Weight": 95.94,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "W",
            "Name": "Tungsten",
            "Atomic Number": 74,
            "Atomic Weight": 183.85,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Sg",
            "Name": "Seaborgium",
            "Atomic Number": 106,
            "Atomic Weight": 266.00,
            "State": "Synthetic",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Mn",
            "Name": "Manganese",
            "Atomic Number": 25,
            "Atomic Weight": 178.49,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Tc",
            "Name": "Technetium",
            "Atomic Number": 43,
            "Atomic Weight": 178.49,
            "State": "Synthetic",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Re",
            "Name": "Rhenium",
            "Atomic Number": 75,
            "Atomic Weight": 178.49,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Bh",
            "Name": "Bohrium",
            "Atomic Number": 107,
            "Atomic Weight": 262.00,
            "State": "Synthetic",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Fe",
            "Name": "Iron",
            "Atomic Number": 26,
            "Atomic Weight": 55.85,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Ru",
            "Name": "Ruthenium",
            "Atomic Number": 44,
            "Atomic Weight": 101.07,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Os",
            "Name": "Osmium",
            "Atomic Number": 76,
            "Atomic Weight": 190.20,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Hs",
            "Name": "Hassium",
            "Atomic Number": 108,
            "Atomic Weight": 265.00,
            "State": "Synthetic",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Co",
            "Name": "Cobalt",
            "Atomic Number": 27,
            "Atomic Weight": 58.93,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Rh",
            "Name": "Rhodium",
            "Atomic Number": 45,
            "Atomic Weight": 102.91,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Ir",
            "Name": "Iridium",
            "Atomic Number": 77,
            "Atomic Weight": 192.22,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Mt",
            "Name": "Meitnerium",
            "Atomic Number": 109,
            "Atomic Weight": 266.00,
            "State": "Synthetic",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Ni",
            "Name": "Nickle",
            "Atomic Number": 28,
            "Atomic Weight": 58.70,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Pd",
            "Name": "Palladium",
            "Atomic Number": 46,
            "Atomic Weight": 106.40,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Pt",
            "Name": "Platinum",
            "Atomic Number": 78,
            "Atomic Weight": 195.09,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Cu",
            "Name": "Copper",
            "Atomic Number": 29,
            "Atomic Weight": 63.55,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Ag",
            "Name": "Silver",
            "Atomic Number": 47,
            "Atomic Weight": 107.97,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Au",
            "Name": "Gold",
            "Atomic Number": 79,
            "Atomic Weight": 196.97,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Zn",
            "Name": "Zinc",
            "Atomic Number": 30,
            "Atomic Weight": 65.37,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Cd",
            "Name": "Cadmium",
            "Atomic Number": 48,
            "Atomic Weight": 112.41,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Hg",
            "Name": "Mercury",
            "Atomic Number": 80,
            "Atomic Weight": 200.59,
            "State": "Liquid",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "B",
            "Name": "Boron",
            "Atomic Number": 5,
            "Atomic Weight": 10.81,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Nonmetals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Al",
            "Name": "Aluminum",
            "Atomic Number": 13,
            "Atomic Weight": 26.98,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Other Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Ga",
            "Name": "Gallium",
            "Atomic Number": 31,
            "Atomic Weight": 69.72,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Other Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "In",
            "Name": "Indium",
            "Atomic Number": 49,
            "Atomic Weight": 69.72,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Other Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Tl",
            "Name": "Thallium",
            "Atomic Number": 81,
            "Atomic Weight": 204.37,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Other Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "C",
            "Name": "Carbon",
            "Atomic Number": 6,
            "Atomic Weight": 12.01,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Nonmetals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Si",
            "Name": "Silicon",
            "Atomic Number": 14,
            "Atomic Weight": 28.09,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Nonmetals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Ge",
            "Name": "Germanium",
            "Atomic Number": 32,
            "Atomic Weight": 72.59,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Other Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Sn",
            "Name": "Tin",
            "Atomic Number": 50,
            "Atomic Weight": 118.69,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Other Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Pb",
            "Name": "Lead",
            "Atomic Number": 82,
            "Atomic Weight": 207.20,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Other Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "N",
            "Name": "Nitrogen",
            "Atomic Number": 7,
            "Atomic Weight": 14.01,
            "State": "Gas",
            "Categories": ["Nonmetals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "P",
            "Name": "Phosphorus",
            "Atomic Number": 15,
            "Atomic Weight": 30.97,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Nonmetals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "As",
            "Name": "Arsenic",
            "Atomic Number": 33,
            "Atomic Weight": 74.92,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Nonmetals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Sb",
            "Name": "Antimony",
            "Atomic Number": 51,
            "Atomic Weight": 121.75,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Other Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Bi",
            "Name": "Bismuth",
            "Atomic Number": 83,
            "Atomic Weight": 208.98,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Other Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "O",
            "Name": "Oxygen",
            "Atomic Number": 8,
            "Atomic Weight": 15.99,
            "State": "Gas",
            "Categories": ["Nonmetals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "S",
            "Name": "Sulfur",
            "Atomic Number": 16,
            "Atomic Weight": 32.06,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Nonmetals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Se",
            "Name": "Selenium",
            "Atomic Number": 34,
            "Atomic Weight": 78.96,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Nonmetals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Te",
            "Name": "Tellurium",
            "Atomic Number": 52,
            "Atomic Weight": 127.60,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Nonmetals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Po",
            "Name": "Polonium",
            "Atomic Number": 84,
            "Atomic Weight": 209.00,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Other Metals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "F",
            "Name": "Fluorine",
            "Atomic Number": 9,
            "Atomic Weight": 18.99,
            "State": "Gas",
            "Categories": ["Nonmetals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Cl",
            "Name": "Chlorine",
            "Atomic Number": 17,
            "Atomic Weight": 35.45,
            "State": "Gas",
            "Categories": ["Nonmetals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Br",
            "Name": "Bromine",
            "Atomic Number": 35,
            "Atomic Weight": 79.90,
            "State": "Liquid",
            "Categories": ["Nonmetals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "I",
            "Name": "Iodine",
            "Atomic Number": 53,
            "Atomic Weight": 126.90,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Nonmetals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "At",
            "Name": "Astatine",
            "Atomic Number": 85,
            "Atomic Weight": 210.00,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Nonmetals"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "He",
            "Name": "Helium",
            "Atomic Number": 2,
            "Atomic Weight": 4.00,
            "State": "Gas",
            "Categories": ["Nobel Gases"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Ne",
            "Name": "Neon",
            "Atomic Number": 10,
            "Atomic Weight": 20.18,
            "State": "Gas",
            "Categories": ["Nobel Gases"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Ar",
            "Name": "Argon",
            "Atomic Number": 18,
            "Atomic Weight": 39.95,
            "State": "Gas",
            "Categories": ["Nobel Gases"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Kr",
            "Name": "Krypton",
            "Atomic Number": 36,
            "Atomic Weight": 83.80,
            "State": "Gas",
            "Categories": ["Nobel Gases"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Xe",
            "Name": "Xenon",
            "Atomic Number": 54,
            "Atomic Weight": 131.30,
            "State": "Gas",
            "Categories": ["Nobel Gases"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Rn",
            "Name": "Radon",
            "Atomic Number": 86,
            "Atomic Weight": 222.00,
            "State": "Gas",
            "Categories": ["Nobel Gases"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": ">| Ce",
            "Name": "Cerium",
            "Atomic Number": 58,
            "Atomic Weight": 140.12,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals", "Lanthanides"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Pr",
            "Name": "Praseodymium",
            "Atomic Number": 59,
            "Atomic Weight": 140.91,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals", "Lanthanides"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Nd",
            "Name": "Neodymium",
            "Atomic Number": 60,
            "Atomic Weight": 144.24,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals", "Lanthanides"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Pm",
            "Name": "Promethium",
            "Atomic Number": 61,
            "Atomic Weight": 145.00,
            "State": "Synthetic",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals", "Lanthanides"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Sm",
            "Name": "Samarium",
            "Atomic Number": 62,
            "Atomic Weight": 150.40,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals", "Lanthanides"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Eu",
            "Name": "Europium",
            "Atomic Number": 63,
            "Atomic Weight": 151.96,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals", "Lanthanides"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Gd",
            "Name": "Gadolinium",
            "Atomic Number": 64,
            "Atomic Weight": 157.25,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals", "Lanthanides"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Tb",
            "Name": "Terbium",
            "Atomic Number": 65,
            "Atomic Weight": 158.93,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals", "Lanthanides"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Dy",
            "Name": "Dyprosium",
            "Atomic Number": 66,
            "Atomic Weight": 162.50,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals", "Lanthanides"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Ho",
            "Name": "Holmium",
            "Atomic Number": 67,
            "Atomic Weight": 164.93,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals", "Lanthanides"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Er",
            "Name": "Erbium",
            "Atomic Number": 68,
            "Atomic Weight": 167.26,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals", "Lanthanides"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Tm",
            "Name": "Thulium",
            "Atomic Number": 69,
            "Atomic Weight": 168.93,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals", "Lanthanides"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Yb",
            "Name": "Ytterbium",
            "Atomic Number": 70,
            "Atomic Weight": 173.04,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals", "Lanthanides"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Lu",
            "Name": "Lutetium",
            "Atomic Number": 71,
            "Atomic Weight": 174.97,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals", "Lanthanides"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": ">| Th",
            "Name": "Thorium",
            "Atomic Number": 90,
            "Atomic Weight": 232.04,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals", "Actinides"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Pa",
            "Name": "Protactinium",
            "Atomic Number": 91,
            "Atomic Weight": 231.04,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals", "Actinides"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "U",
            "Name": "Uranium",
            "Atomic Number": 92,
            "Atomic Weight": 238.03,
            "State": "Solid",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals", "Actinides"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Np",
            "Name": "Neptunium",
            "Atomic Number": 93,
            "Atomic Weight": 237.05,
            "State": "Synthetic",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals", "Actinides"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Pu",
            "Name": "Plutonium",
            "Atomic Number": 94,
            "Atomic Weight": 244.00,
            "State": "Synthetic",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals", "Actinides"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Am",
            "Name": "Americium",
            "Atomic Number": 95,
            "Atomic Weight": 243.00,
            "State": "Synthetic",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals", "Actinides"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Cm",
            "Name": "Curium",
            "Atomic Number": 96,
            "Atomic Weight": 247,
            "State": "Synthetic",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals", "Actinides"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Bk",
            "Name": "Berkelium",
            "Atomic Number": 97,
            "Atomic Weight": 247,
            "State": "Synthetic",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals", "Actinides"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Cf",
            "Name": "Californium",
            "Atomic Number": 98,
            "Atomic Weight": 247,
            "State": "Synthetic",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals", "Actinides"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Es",
            "Name": "Einsteinium",
            "Atomic Number": 99,
            "Atomic Weight": 252.00,
            "State": "Synthetic",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals", "Actinides"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Fm",
            "Name": "Fermium",
            "Atomic Number": 100,
            "Atomic Weight": 257.00,
            "State": "Synthetic",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals", "Actinides"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Md",
            "Name": "Mendelevium",
            "Atomic Number": 101,
            "Atomic Weight": 260.00,
            "State": "Synthetic",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals", "Actinides"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "No",
            "Name": "Nobelium",
            "Atomic Number": 102,
            "Atomic Weight": 259,
            "State": "Synthetic",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals", "Actinides"]
        },
        {
            "Alias": "Lr",
            "Name": "Lawrencium",
            "Atomic Number": 103,
            "Atomic Weight": 262,
            "State": "Synthetic",
            "Categories": ["Trans Metals", "Actinides"]
        }
    ]
}
```

## `elements_layout_map.json`

```
{
    "version": 1,
    "map": {
        "H": { "row": 1, "column" : 0 },
        "Li": { "row": 2, "column" : 0 },
        "Na": { "row": 3, "column": 0 },
        "K": { "row": 4, "column": 0 },
        "Rb": { "row": 5, "column": 0 },
        "Cs": { "row": 6, "column": 0 },
        "Fr": { "row": 7, "column": 0 },
        "Be": { "row": 2, "column": 1 },
        "Mg": { "row": 3, "column": 1 },
        "Ca": { "row": 4, "column": 1 },
        "Sr": { "row": 5, "column": 1 },
        "Ba": { "row": 6, "column": 1 },
        "Ra": { "row": 7, "column": 1 },
        "Sc": { "row": 4, "column": 2 },
        "Y": { "row": 5, "column": 2 },
        "La   >|": { "row": 6, "column": 2 },
        "Ac   >|": { "row": 7, "column": 2 },
        "Ti": { "row": 4, "column": 3 },
        "Zr": { "row": 5, "column": 3 },
        "Hf": { "row": 6, "column": 3 },
        "Rf": { "row": 7, "column": 3 },
        "V": { "row": 4, "column": 4 },
        "Nb": { "row": 5, "column": 4 },
        "Ta": { "row": 6, "column": 4 },
        "Ha": { "row": 7, "column": 4 },
        "Cr": { "row": 4, "column": 5 },
        "Mo": { "row": 5, "column": 5 },
        "W": { "row": 6, "column": 5 },
        "Sg": { "row": 7, "column": 5 },
        "Mn": { "row": 4, "column": 6 },
        "Tc": { "row": 5, "column": 6 },
        "Re": { "row": 6, "column": 6 },
        "Bh": { "row": 7, "column": 6 },
        "Fe": { "row": 4, "column": 7 },
        "Ru": { "row": 5, "column": 7 },
        "Os": { "row": 6, "column": 7 },
        "Hs": { "row": 7, "column": 7 },
        "Co": { "row": 4, "column": 8 },
        "Rh": { "row": 5, "column": 8 },
        "Ir": { "row": 6, "column": 8 },
        "Mt": { "row": 7, "column": 8 },
        "Ni": { "row": 4, "column": 9 },
        "Pd": { "row": 5, "column": 9 },
        "Pt": { "row": 6, "column": 9 },
        "Cu": { "row": 4, "column": 10 },
        "Ag": { "row": 5, "column": 10 },
        "Au": { "row": 6, "column": 10 },
        "Zn": { "row": 4, "column": 11 },
        "Cd": { "row": 5, "column": 11 },
        "Hg": { "row": 6, "column": 11 },
        "B": { "row": 2, "column": 12 },
        "Al": { "row": 3, "column": 12 },
        "Ga": { "row": 4, "column": 12 },
        "In": { "row": 5, "column": 12 },
        "Tl": { "row": 6, "column": 12 },
        "C": { "row": 2, "column": 13 },
        "Si": { "row": 3, "column": 13 },
        "Ge": { "row": 4, "column": 13 },
        "Sn": { "row": 5, "column": 13 },
        "Pb": { "row": 6, "column": 13 },
        "N": { "row": 2, "column": 14 },
        "P": { "row": 3, "column": 14 },
        "As": { "row": 4, "column": 14 },
        "Sb": { "row": 5, "column": 14 },
        "Bi": { "row": 6, "column": 14 },
        "O": { "row": 2, "column": 15 },
        "S": { "row": 3, "column": 15 },
        "Se": { "row": 4, "column": 15 },
        "Te": { "row": 5, "column": 15 },
        "Po": { "row": 6, "column": 15 },
        "F": { "row": 2, "column": 16 },
        "Cl": { "row": 3, "column": 16 },
        "Br": { "row": 4, "column": 16 },
        "I": { "row": 5, "column": 16 },
        "At": { "row": 6, "column": 16 },
        "He": { "row": 1, "column": 17 },
        "Ne": { "row": 2, "column": 17 },
        "Ar": { "row": 3, "column": 17 },
        "Kr": { "row": 4, "column": 17 },
        "Xe": { "row": 5, "column": 17 },
        "Rn": { "row": 6, "column": 17 },
        ">| Ce": { "row": 11, "column": 3 },
        "Pr": { "row": 11, "column": 4 },
        "Nd": { "row": 11, "column": 5 },
        "Pm": { "row": 11, "column": 6 },
        "Sm": { "row": 11, "column": 7 },
        "Eu": { "row": 11, "column": 8 },
        "Gd": { "row": 11, "column": 9 },
        "Tb": { "row": 11, "column": 10 },
        "Dy": { "row": 11, "column": 11 },
        "Ho": { "row": 11, "column": 12 },
        "Er": { "row": 11, "column": 13 },
        "Tm": { "row": 11, "column": 14 },
        "Yb": { "row": 11, "column": 15 },
        "Lu": { "row": 11, "column": 16 },
        ">| Th": { "row": 12, "column": 3 },
        "Pa": { "row": 12, "column": 4 },
        "U" : { "row": 12, "column": 5 },   
        "Np": { "row": 12, "column": 6 },   
        "Pu": { "row": 12, "column": 7 },   
        "Am": { "row": 12, "column": 8 },   
        "Cm": { "row": 12, "column": 9 },   
        "Bk": { "row": 12, "column": 10 },   
        "Cf": { "row": 12, "column": 11 },   
        "Es": { "row": 12, "column": 12 },   
        "Fm": { "row": 12, "column": 13 },   
        "Md": { "row": 12, "column": 14 },   
        "No": { "row": 12, "column": 15 },   
        "Lr": { "row": 12, "column": 16 }  
    }
}
```

## `color_map.json`

```
{
    "version": 1,
    "map": {
        "Alkali Metals": "grey",
        "Alkaline Earth Metals": "light green",
        "Trans Metals": "light goldenrod",
        "Nonmetals": "Light Blue",
        "Other Metals": "Light Pink",
        "Nobel Gases": "indian red"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Cool project!

I would definitely bring all of the hard-coded information about the elements to the top of the module, this will make your code much more readable as well as enabling you to make it shorter as I will show.

Personally I would probably use a dictionary where the columns are the keys. And since the rows that are used vary from column to column, you'll need that information in there too so the values of the dictionary could be lists of (row, element) pairs like this:

```
elements_by_column = {
    1: [
        (1, ('H', 'Hydrogen', 'Atomic # = 1\nAtomic Weight =1.01\nState = Gas\nCategory = Alkali Metals')),
        (2, ('Li', 'Lithium', 'Atomic # = 3\nAtomic Weight = 6.94\nState = Solid\nCategory = Alkali Metals')),
        (3, ('Na', 'Sodium', 'Atomic # = 11\nAtomic Weight = 22.99\nState = Solid\nCategory = Alkali Metals')),
        ...
    ],
    ...
}
```

As far as I can tell, the only other thing that varies from column to column is the background colour, so you can define that at the beginning too:

```
column_colors = {
    1: "grey",
    2: "light goldenrod",
    ...
}
```

With this done, you should be able to replace the code for making the buttons with something like the following:

```
num_cols = len(elements_by_column.keys())

for col in range(1, num_cols + 1):
    for row, element in elements_by_column[col]:
        tk.Button(self,
                text=element[0],
                width=5,
                height=2,
                bg=column_colors[col],
                command=lambda text=element:  self.name(text[1]) & self.info(text[2])).grid(row=row, column=col)
```

I haven't tested this out so there may be some slight adjustments to be made but it should be equivalent to what you have at the moment. I hope that helps!